# Convex Optimization 3.2.5 Minimization why drop $\epsilon$ in proving partial minimization preserves convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[image]

[image]

Why does it say **"Since this holds for any $\epsilon  \le 0$"**? In my opinion, $g(x_1) \leq f(x_1,y_1)$, $g(x_2) \leq f(x_2,y_2)$ indicated by definition 3.16,  thus $\epsilon$ cannot be dropped。

Comment: It says "for any $\epsilon >0$". The argument in that line is "if $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $a\leq b$".

Comment: so you mean $f(x_1,y_1)  \leq g(x_1) + \epsilon$ and $f(x_2,y_2)  \leq g(x_2) + \epsilon $  for any small positive $\epsilon$ ? If definition 3.16 exits,  why not $g(x_1) \leq f(x_1,y_1)$ and $g(x_2) \leq f(x_2,y_2)$ and then $\theta f(x_1,y_1) + (1-\theta) f(x_2,y_2) \ge \theta g(x_1) + (1-\theta) g(x_2)$, by introducing $\epsilon$ then droping it, the relationship makes a reversal, it seems incredible, I am confused.

Comment: This is how all $\inf$'s work. For example, $\inf_{n \ge 1} \sin\frac1n = 0$. This simultaneously means (1) $0 \le \sin \frac1n$ for all $n \ge 1$, and (2) for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find some $n$ such that $\sin \frac1n \le 0 + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

The source of this inequality is the definition of the infimum. In particular,

$$
g(x) = \inf_{y \in C} f(x, y)
$$

implies that you can find a sequence of points $y_k$ and $\epsilon_k \downarrow 0$ such that $f(x, y_k) \leq g(x) + \epsilon_k$. Here, $\epsilon_k > 0$ but can be driven arbitrarily close to $0$.

Note that this does not contradict that fact that $g(x) \leq f(x, y)$ for any $y$. Indeed, replacing in the inequality above just gives

$$
g(x) \leq f(x, y_k) \leq g(x) + \epsilon_k,
$$

which is valid as long as $\epsilon_k \ge 0$.